# webgl video delay / store and access past frames

Tags: javascript, video, textures, buffer, webgl

I'd like to create a realtime video delay using webgl. Essentially I want to have a rolling buffer that would keep a certain number of past frames available for me to use within a shader.

I've already accomplished this using openFrameworks and ofxPlaymodes, but I'm having trouble visualizing how exactly I would port this over to javascript/webgl.

Conceptually I can imagine how this is possible. First I would create an array of textures. As the feed plays, I iterate through the texture array storing a frame in each texture slot and keeping track of it's index.

I gave this a shot, but I feel like I'm heading in the wrong direction here. This just gets me an array where each indice has the same frame.

```
var textureArray = [];
var videoFrame;

function createAndSetupTexture(gl){
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
  return texture;
}


function setupTexArray(){
  for (var i = 0; i<numFrames; i++){
    videoFrame = createAndSetupTexture(gl);
    videoFrame.image = video;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, videoFrame);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, videoFrame.image);
    textureArray.push(videoFrame);
  }
}
```

I've seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705781/video-delay-buffer-in-processing-2-0) about doing this in processing, but they are using pixel data instead of textures.

I'd prefer to do as much as I can on the gpu to keep things speedy. At the most I'd like to get a 10 second delay at 240p, which I realize is not an insignificant amount of frames. With my openframeworks app I've been able to get up to ~15 seconds at 720p before running out of memory.

Can anyone help get me started with this or perhaps point to another project that has accomplished what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Why isn't what you did in your previous program exactly applicable to do it in WebGL?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to setup my circular buffer. The app I made before was hiding much of what was going on in an ofx addon. For the buffer it's using a deque to hold the frames, and then if the buffer is full, begins deleting the first frame that was added. They are using a separate class called a header to calculate the position within the buffer and do things like set a delay.

I think it's going to be a matter of translating the relevant bits to js/webgl. I was hoping that perhaps someone knew of or had created a similar project or library, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: a circular buffer is basic programming. Google it? Sorry I'm not trying to be mean but it's arguably not something that should be answered under this question. In fact stackoverflow has many answers on circular buffers. One simple way in JavaScript is to make an array. `push` new things on the end array, `shift` old ones off the beginning. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/ENNC8/)